# Javascript: Convert timestamp to human readable date?

Tags: javascript

I'm simply trying to convert a timestamp back into a human readable date but what I get when converted is strange and wrong.

This is how I save the timestamp:

```
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
localStorag.setItem("mytimestamp", timestamp);
```

and this is how I get it back and convert it to readable date:

```
var mydate = localStorag.getItem("mytimestamp");
var jsDate = new Date(mydate*1000);

alert(jsDate);
```

The `jsDate` is wrong and I don't understand what's causing it!

Could someone please advise on this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use the `Number` data type instead of `date * 1000` to achieve this. See code example below:

```
// generate a timestamp
var timestamp = Number(new Date()) //1479895361931
```

Then

```
// get the date representation from the timestamp
var date = new Date(timestamp) // Wed Nov 23 2016 18:03:25 GMT+0800 (WITA)
```

Comment: Try `var date = new Date(timestamp).toDateString();` for a truly readable date (see answer below)

Comment: You can try new Date() for epoch or unix timestamp to date conversion. Check this https://www.epochconvert.com/programming/javascript

Answer (score 18):

Here is an easy solution using the [`toDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toDateString) method:

```
const date = new Date(timestamp).toDateString();
console.log(date);
```

This will return something like: **Thu Jul 14 2016**

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, `Thu Feb 28 2019` is *so much more* readable than `Fri Mar 01 2019 09:02:13 GMT+0100 (Central European Time)`

Comment: For i18n check out [`Date.toLocaleDateString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) or [`Intl.DateTimeFormat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 5):

The cause of the issue here is when you multiply the timestamp by 1000.

If you simply pass `myDate` to the `Date` constructor you should get the correct time -

```
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
localStorage.setItem("mytimestamp", timestamp);
// ...
var mydateStr = localStorage.getItem("mytimestamp");
var myDate = Number(mydateStr); // convert the string back to a number
var jsDate = new Date(mydate);
```

It's true that Javascript deals with milliseconds but since you are generating the timestamp with Javascript and then reading it back also with Javascript, no conversion is needed - you can use the value as-is.

---

As was pointed out to me by @manish in the comments, the value stored in localStorage will be a string - remember to convert it back to a number before passing it to the Date constructor.

Comment: this will return a Invalid Date https://jsfiddle.net/xdkon614/ have a look

Comment: Thanks @Manish! You are indeed correct! Fixing my post now

Comment: You are welcome. The reason behind this i have explained in my Answer.

Answer (score 4):

Try using `moment.js`. It add functions such as

```
moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a'); // November 23rd 2016, 12:03:36 pm
moment().format('dddd');                    // Wednesday
moment().format("MMM Do YY");               // Nov 23rd 16
moment().format('YYYY [escaped] YYYY');     // 2016 escaped 2016
moment().format();                          // 2016-11-23T12:03:36+02:00
```

Comment: I prefer not to use any other plugins to be honest.. its such a basic and simple task so I'd rather not to use any other plugins.

Comment: Adding a library just for this specific case is overkill IMO. This is something that can be done with native JS unless you need a very specific time format.

Comment: You guys are probably right. Another library is probably overkill. But it's just another option, and usually when trying to manipulate dates and times, you reach using this library pretty soon

Answer (score 2):

```
var yourTimestamp = localStorag.getItem("mytimestamp");
jsDate = new Date(yourTimestamp);

jsDateValues = [
   jsDate.getFullYear(),
   jsDate.getMonth()+1,
   jsDate.getDate(),
   jsDate.getHours(),
   jsDate.getMinutes(),
   jsDate.getSeconds(),
];
alert(jsDateValues); //=> [2011, 3, 25, 23, 0, 0]
```

and you can use the baove values and print in which format you wnat e.g dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: This code will suffer from the same issue since you are still multiplying a millisecond value by 1000. `localStorag.getItem("mytimestamp");` holds the timestamp already in milliseconds.

Comment: yes your right, i thoght the value i'm getting is in milliseconds .

Comment: try with this  @Lix , most propably it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that when you store something in localstorage its being stored as string `'1479895747557'` and not a number So when you get the timestamp back from localstorage its not a number its a string. Though when you multiply it the value actually changes due to internal conversion it becomes `1479895747557000` and this represents a different date from the one you saved. So the solution would be to convert the string back to a number. Here is the code that works fine.

```js
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
localStorage.setItem("mytimestamp", timestamp);
var mydate = localStorage.getItem("mytimestamp");
var jsDate = new Date(Number(mydate));
alert(jsDate);
```

Here is the code that does not performs the conversion back to number this will give you an Invalid Date.

```js
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
localStorage.setItem("mytimestamp", timestamp);

var mydate = localStorage.getItem("mytimestamp");

var jsDate = new Date(mydate);

alert(jsDate);
```

**[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/xdkon614/)**

Answer (score 1):

if your date is string and looks like this "2023-11-08T08:49:35.000000Z". You don't need any library for formatting it.

```
const date = new Date("2023-11-08T08:49:35.000000Z").toDateString();
console.log(date); // "Wed Nov 08 2023"
```

Answer (score -1):

- [Reference](https://shadowgaming100.github.io/W3Schools/js/js_date_methods.html)
- [demo](https://codepen.io/ChemBioScripting/pen/qBpJGBE)

> **JS Code**

```js
var timestamp = Number(new Date());
localStorage.setItem("mytimestamp", timestamp);
var mydate = localStorage.getItem("mytimestamp");
var jsDate = new Date(Number(mydate));
alert(jsDate);

const months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];

const days = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var year = jsDate.getFullYear(),
    monthnum = jsDate.getMonth() + 1,
    twodigitsmonthnum = ("0" + monthnum).slice(-2),
    monthname = months[jsDate.getMonth()],
    daymonthnum = jsDate.getDate(),
    twodigitsdaymonthnum = ("0" + daymonthnum).slice(-2),
    dayname = days[jsDate.getDay()],
    hours = jsDate.getHours(),
    twodigitshours = ("0" + hours).slice(-2),
    minutes = jsDate.getMinutes(),
    twodigitsminutes = ("0" + minutes).slice(-2),
    seconds = jsDate.getSeconds(),
    twodigitsseconds = ("0" + seconds).slice(-2),
    milliseconds = jsDate.getMilliseconds();

alert(dayname + ", " + daymonthnum + " " + monthname + " " + year + ", " + twodigitshours + ":" + twodigitsminutes + ":" + twodigitsseconds + "." + milliseconds);
```